# How to correctly log trades using backtrader in python?

Tags: python, datetime

Using data from csv file in 60 minute format. Trying to log all buy/sell decisions using backtrader backtester.

Issue: The time logger doesn't seem to work properly as all hours are outputted as "23:59:59.999989" when this is not the case.

See sample code:

```
def log(self, txt, dt=None):
    dt = dt or self.data.datetime.datetime(0)
    print('%s, %s' % (dt, txt)) 


def next(self):
    if self.data.close > self.sma1:
        self.buy()
        self.log('BUY CREATE, exectype Market, price %.2f' % self.data.close[0])

#Get Data
data = btfeeds.GenericCSVData(dataname='AAPL.csv',fromdate=datetime.datetime(2018, 1, 2),todate=datetime.datetime(2020, 4, 28),nullvalue=0.0,dtformat=('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'),datetime=0,open=1,low=2,high=3,close=4,volume=5,openinterest=6)
```

Sample Output:

```
2019-07-12 23:59:59.999989, BUY CREATE, exectype Market, price 203.52
2019-07-12 23:59:59.999989, BUY CREATE, exectype Market, price 203.30
2019-07-12 23:59:59.999989, BUY CREATE, exectype Market, price 203.24
2019-07-12 23:59:59.999989, BUY CREATE, exectype Market, price 203.24
2019-07-15 23:59:59.999989, BUY CREATE, exectype Market, price 204.11
```

Data & Format from Csv file:

```
2018-01-02  9:30:00 AM
```

Comment: @kszl can you kindly provide code explanation/example. Thanks

Comment: I haven't tested it and that's why I only post it as a comment. Data format seems to be incorrect. There's no am/pm directive there and also hours aren't padded with zeros. Have you tried something like '%Y-%m-%d %-H:%M:%S %p'?

Comment: @kszl This doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

This problem also took me few hours. And I find the solution from another web. [enter link description here](https://community.backtrader.com/topic/2795/date-changing-but-time-not-changing/2)

For minute data tell cerebro that you are using minute data (timeframe) and how many minutes per bar (compression).

```
#Get Data
data = btfeeds.GenericCSVData(
dataname='AAPL.csv',
fromdate=datetime.datetime(2018, 1, 2),
todate=datetime.datetime(2020, 4, 28),
nullvalue=0.0,

dtformat=('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'),
**timeframe=bt.TimeFrame.Minutes,**

datetime=0,
open=1,
low=2,
high=3,
close=4,
volume=5,
openinterest=6)
```